# Override ToString() method with List<>

Tags: c#

What I have tried so far:

```
private List<Item> item = new List<Item>();

    public List<Item> Item { get; set; } //Provide Access to List item

    public Inventory() // Default constructor made to initialize default List<> value
    {
        Item = new List<Item>()
        {
            new Item("iPod"),
            new Item("Samsung"),
            new Item("Motorolla"),
            new Item("Nokia")
        };
    }

override String ToString() {
  return ...?
}
```

How do I implement an override ToString() method in my class that returns the default List<> values to the user

Comment: You override it in Item...

Comment: Theres already an override ToString implemented in there

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the code above in a class that you just want to call something like `Console.WriteLine(itemsClassInstance)` on and have it output like `item1, item2, ..., itemN`?

Comment: Not posible, because the returned type of toString() funtion as string, and you not returned another type from  this, you can return a concatenated string of ítems.

Comment: Yep thats the ideal output. Whenever the inventory class is called, the ToString() method will now display whatever is on List<>

Comment: In creating an example for my answer, I noted that you never assign the list you create in the Inventory() constructor to the item field. I've corrected this in my example.

Comment: Also, you should change the `Item` property to readonly (You do not want to enable other classes to do `MyClass.Item = new List<Item>`), and you should consider exposing it as either `IEnumerable<Item>` or `IReadOnlyCollection<Item>`, so that other classes will have to go through a method in your class to add or remove items. That way, your class have more control over the content of the list.

Answer (score 5):

Since you state that you've already overrided the `ToString()` method for individual list items, you can do something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return string.Join(", ", item);
}
```

So, assuming your Item's ToString() method just returns the string you pass in to create it, you would end up with a string like this: `iPod, Samsung, Motorola, Nokia`.

If your list is likely to grow to a large amount, and you just want a preview, you could take the first 5 items to build the string from like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return string.Join(", ", item.Take(5));
}
```

By the way, I'd recommend calling your `Item` property `Items` since it is a collection and not a single item.

Example [here](http://rextester.com/TIS63528).

Comment: And it even works inside interpolated strings! Thanks